# Flipper with inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, flipper

I'm facing an issue with [Flipper](https://github.com/flippercloud/flipper) which is actually not really one.

I have a `User` on the mail app an `MyEngine::User` on an engine `MyEngine`.

```rb
# implementation in the engine
class MyEngine::User < User
  # ...
end
```

```rb
User.first.flipper_id
# => User;1

MyEngine::User.first.flipper_id
# => MyEngine::User;1
```

But actually, `User;1` and `MyEngine::User;1` are the same user. To avoid this, I need to make as many records on Flipper as I have subclasses defined on each engine. It's painful.

Should I pipe the normal `Flipper.enabled?(:something, user)` with a group where I check the inheritance? It's a bit ugly isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issued raised on the gem. Here is the [PR#758](https://github.com/flippercloud/flipper/pull/758)